# how to make a form not submit if the checkbox is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form in a ecommerce solution. I dont have access to the code other than that i can add a footer and header. So i can write some js and css codes.

I want to add a checkbox which i can by using

```
  <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox1" class="default-input sale-text-req"/>Please read the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

I want to make sure that form is not submitted until the checkbox is selected. I do have the name/id of the order button. Any idea how this can be achieved

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be to prevent the submit button from being enabled until the user has selected the terms and conditions. You could also bake more validation in, in this form:

```
 function checkTerms() {
     if(document.formname.checkboxname.checked)
     {
         document.formname.submitname.disabled=false;
     }
     else
     {
         document.formname.submitname.disabled=true;
     }
 }
```

OR with JQuery:

```
 function checkTerms() {
     if($('input[name="checkbox1"]').is(":checked")
     {
         $('input[name="submitname"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
     else
     {
         $('input[name="submitname"]').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
 }
```

Finally on your checkbox you would fire the validation when the click occurs:

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox1" class="default-input sale-text-req" onclick="checkTerms();"/>
```

Comment: Nice to find this but would like button to be greyed out until checkbox is ticked, it does stop submit but you can't then tick the box and click the button.

Answer (score 8):

Bind validation to your form's submit event like so:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    if(!$("input[name='checkbox1']").is(":checked")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: You missed the closing if `)`.

Comment: It didnt work... not sure what the problem is.. here is url https://brianhaskins.infusionsoft.com/saleform/nathniiu

Comment: @Prady I missed a closing rparen on the if check as pimvdb mentioned. Might try it again with the edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onsubmit` attribute, check for the value of the element. If it's unchecked, use `return false`.